# how to retrieve data from mysql in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

Example:- This is sample webpages

```
Name      |       details
------------------------------------------------
James     |        name:James
john      |        mobile: 43435676778
smith     |        Address: xyz
willam    |        contact no : 323565
```

Name column also retrieve from MySQL database
If I click Name and it shows on details. details also retrieve from MySQL database how to proceed

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"
  placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<%
Connection con=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
String sql="select empname from emp_details";
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample?useSSL=FALSE&&characterEncoding=latin1","username","password");
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next())
      {
        %>
        <ul class="results list-unstyled" id="myUL" >
          <li class="first" id="rests" name="rests">
            <a href="#"><%=rs.getString("empname")%></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <%
      }
}catch(Exception e)
{    
  out.print(e);
}
%>
```

Comment: Please Ajax call to get the data, JSTL for extracting the data to display

Comment: Fix your code indentation its way off the screen.

Comment: You should research Servlets to do its

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an Ajax call (an asynchronous framework) to do that. You also miss the where condition of the statement where to put the name you choose

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should follow MVC Pattern where your data Layer is separated from view layer.
So in Here crate a Seperate Class for JDBC Connection and DAO (Data Access Object) Class to query the Data Base. Now use this classes from JSP to get the Data.
[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-data-access-layer-using-jdbc) is good tutorial for refrence.